# AJAX and JavaScript script loader

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I would like to know how to load JavaScript file after loading of page via AJAX?
The problem is:
I have music player which uses JS file whith infomation about tracks.
After that I load page all works nice. But when I load another page via AJAX my script doesn't work at page which I called.

Code looks like this:

```
function showContent(link,link2) {
    var cont = document.getElementById('content');
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
    window.history.replaceState('', 'Title', link2);
    var http = createRequestObject();                   
    if( http ) {
        http.open('get', link);                         
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {         

            if(http.readyState == 4) {

                cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;     
            }
        }
        http.send(null);    
    } else {
        document.location = link;   
    }
}
function createRequestObject() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }
    catch(e) {
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }
        catch(e) {
            try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }
            catch(e) { return null; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use angular-soundmanager2.js to make player alive.
And this cut of code won't work at page which I load after linking to this page

```
 <h5>Songs</h5>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="song in songs">

                    <button music-player="play" add-song="song">{{ song.title }}</button>
                    <button music-player add-song="song">+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <button play-all="songs">Play all</button>
            <button play-all="songs" data-play="false">Add all</button>
```

It has to show me playlist. But I get nothing.

Comment: Try to use a `class` instead of `id`...remember that `id` are unique...also if you are loading content via ajax, you should bind a event to the container with `on`...

Answer (score 0):

You must be binding the DOM element with javascript. On document ready you call something like this, $('#someDiv').makePlayer(). So, page loads it works fine. But when you make ajax, I guess you are replacing that page content on ajax. If you are removing and loading the DOM element again on which you called the makeplayer() earlier. You have to call makePlayer thing again after your ajax call.

Comment: I do this. But this returns nothing.